# How to do I increase the speed of enemies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried the following code but the speed boost only applied to the newly generating enemies.I have made it so that the player itself dose'nt move but the enemies do.

The generator of the enemies
I used the spawnpoints array

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine;


public class Generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] EnemySpawns;
    public GameObject[] EnemyPrefab;
    public float timeLeft = 1.0f;
    public float usesamevarasabove = 1.0f;
    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            int RandEnemy = Random.Range(0, EnemyPrefab.Length);
            int RandSpawPoint = Random.Range(0, EnemySpawns.Length);
            Instantiate(EnemyPrefab[0], EnemySpawns[RandSpawPoint].position, transform.rotation);
            timeLeft = usesamevarasabove;
        }
    }
}
```

The curse
there will be 6 curses, 3 good 3 bad
in the bad curse i want to increase the speed at which the enemies move
but when the player and the curse collide the already existing enemies dont change but the newly generated ones have higher speed. I am applying the speed change to the enemy prefab but it still dosent apply to

```
int curse = Random.Range(1,1);
        Debug.Log(curse);
        if(curse == 0)
        {
            
        }
        else if(curse == 1)
        {
            em = e.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>();
            em.speed = new Vector2(10, 0);
            
        }
```

the enemy speed

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine;
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(5, 0);
    private Vector2 screenBounds;
    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(speed.x * -1, 0, 0);
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);
        if(transform.position.x < -20){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call the `curse` codeblock?

Comment: using OnTriggerEnter and i have a curse tag on the curse

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you mentioned applying the new movement speed to the Enemy Prefab. This will indeed cause all of the new objects spawned to have the increased movement speed.

However all of the previously spawned enemies have their own instances of the EnemyMovement script and thus will still have the previous Speed.

In the generator you will need to make sure to keep a List of all the previously spawned Enemies and update those when the player collides with the curse.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] EnemySpawns;
    public GameObject[] EnemyPrefab;
    public List<GameObject> spawnedEnemies = new List<GameObject>();
    public float timeLeft = 1.0f;
    public float usesamevarasabove = 1.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            int RandEnemy = Random.Range(0, EnemyPrefab.Length);
            int RandSpawPoint = Random.Range(0, EnemySpawns.Length);
            GameObject tempGO = Instantiate(EnemyPrefab[0], EnemySpawns[RandSpawPoint].position,         transform.rotation);
            spawnedEnemies.Add(tempGO);
            timeLeft = usesamevarasabove;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateEnemySpeed(Vector2 newSpeed) {
        for(int i = 0; i < spawnedEnemies.Count; i++) {
             spawnedEnemies[i].GetComponent<EnemyMovement>().speed = newSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

I added a List that keeps track of all the spawned enemies to your Generator script and added a function that loops through all these spawned objects and updates the speed in all of them.
When the player collides with the curse just make it call the UpdateEnemySpeed function with the new speed and it should update all the previously spawned enemies.

Edit:
Also you may need to remove an enemy that gets destroyed from the list or it might have empty entries.

Comment: It is showing an error

Comment: 'List<GameObject>' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GameObject>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ArnavShukla I'm so sorry I typed this from the top of my head and I made a small mistake. I will update it

Comment: Okay I adjusted it and it should work as intended now. I did not add the square brackets with the id of the current List object so it was trying to do GetComponent on the whole list

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Generator.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Generator.cs:22)

Comment: I think that should be a problem with the fact that your spawned enemies get destroyed when they get further away than -20 on the screen.
Edit:
The List dynamically resizes when elements get removed. So maybe an element gets removed and the list gets smaller while you're adjusting the enemy movement speed?

Comment: Nevermind what I wrote previously. I see that rule 22 is the Instantiate. I copied over what you wrote previously and as long as the EnemyPrefab array has an element at the 0 index & EnemySpawns has at least one element it should get spawned correctly.

If either or both of these arrays have no elements it will try to access the element at id 0 while there is none and throw the Index out of bounds array

Comment: so should i just remove the destroy?

Comment: even when i removed the enemy destroy code it is still showing the error

Comment: I dont think you understood Generator.cs

Comment: basically i used spawnpoints and i took a random spawnpoint and instanciated an enemy in the position of the spawnpoint this repeats every 0.25 seconds

Comment: also it didnt fix the issue

Comment: the newly generated ones are faster than the older ones

Comment: The thing about the destroy was an incorrect assumption on my part. Are you calling the UpdateEnemySpeed function when the player touches the curse? Otherwise please post all the code related to the curse.

Comment: yes i called it when the player touches the currse

Comment: nvm i solved it

Comment: i used a variable

Comment: im so happy rn istg it took 10 hours

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can just make enemy speed a static field:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine;
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Vector2 speed = new Vector2(5, 0);
    private Vector2 screenBounds;
    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(speed.x * -1, 0, 0);
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(movement);
        if(transform.position.x < -20){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This way change should be applied to all objects that are using EnemyMovement script, because static field is shared by all instances of a class